# how ignore gap between ids when restart server and use allocation size in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

when im using allocationsize=10 in hibernate and insert 5 records in db ids will be 1,2,3,4,5.when i restart server next insert id has 5 gap and start from 11,12,13,...is there any way to solve this?is this important to have not gap in ids?
ive searched and set

```
<prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
```

but this didnt resolved my problem.
my entity annotation:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "c")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "c",sequenceName = "c2",allocationSize =10)
```

spring.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="brc.com"/><!--ToPackageAddress-->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>-->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

sequence:

```
SEQUENCE C2 INCREMENT BY 10 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 NOCACHE;
```

Comment: Why would you care about gaps in your sequence? You're going to get them anyway as transactions that read the sequences next value get rolled-back, etc. If you need a value that is sequential for that record, you shouldn't be relying on the synthetic key for that.

Comment: so there is no need that ids be sequential?this gaps are not important later?note that milions of records will be inserted to this db.

Comment: Nope, and you've set a max value that I can't even put into words, but lets pretend that it wasn't that long, lets say it was 32bit - that would give you enough room for 4billion+ records (2billion+ if you only want positive values), or 64bit which would probably take you until the heat death of the solar system to use up. The worst case scenario is that you would end up asking your DBA to widen the column at some date in the future, and when you're dealing with billions of rows, even millions have a minor impact.

Comment: In most cases, you can ignore the gaps that may occur. You'll restart the app far less frequently on production than you do during development. It's good to know, that an Integer would work for almost two months if you generated a new identifier each millisecond with no gaps, and a Long would last for about 300 million years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after many searches I concluded that there is no way to fix this gap.every time that we restart web app or server if there is allocated ids it will make the gap and sequence will increment.
in huge inserts to db its very better to set allocation size of sequence to a bigger number and forget about gap cause it will not make a problem in future.

in particular moments we can take last id from db and in our java code so return the sequence to last id.but if there is many transactions that can interfere with returning sequence we only can set allocation size to 1 or save not used ids  and use them later with some codes.